# intellij: creating array list with generics

Tags: intellij-idea

I used to have an option in `Intellij`: it was highlighting the following row:

```
List<String> shipments = new ArrayList();
```

and suggesting to change it to:

```
List<String> shipments = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now I changed something in intentions (or inspections?) configuration, and it suggests to change the above row to:

```
ArrayList shipments = new ArrayList();
```

What can be done to fix it?

thank you

P.S: I searched through intellij options, did not find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your `Make Type Generic` intention is turned on (Located under Settings -> Intentions -> Declaration)

Comment: it is checked, actually everything is checked under Settings -> Intentions -> Declaration)

Comment: Any chance that you've suppressed the intention then, for the given line/method/class?

Comment: it doesnt work for the whole project. can I come back to the default intentions settings?

Comment: I guess you can delete the whole Settings directory (C:\Users\<username>\.IntelliJIdea11\config), but it will wipe out your other settings as well

Comment: thanks for help. maybe something is wrong with my Intellij -> inspections settings..